# Combine gam smooths of multiple clusters in an mgcViz plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, mgcv

I have gam smooths for several clusters coming from a model-based clustering code combining unequal length time series and I would like to display them along with the data.

The mgcViz package provides excellent visualizations for individual clusters but I don't see how to combine them. Perhaps it's because it aims at visualizing several effects rather than several clusters. Nevertheless, its capability is very close to what I need, so here is a reproducible example (adapted from https://mfasiolo.github.io/mgcViz/articles/mgcviz.html):

```
library(mgcViz)
n = 1e3
z = rnorm(n)
dat = data.frame(x = rep(z, times = 2),
                 y = rep(c(1,2), each = n) + c(sin(z), 0.5*z^2) + rnorm(2*n)/4,
                 g = factor(rep(1:2, each = n)))

b <- lapply(1:2, function(i, dat) gam(y ~ s(x), data = dat[dat$g == i, ]),
            dat = dat)

plot(getViz(b[[1]])) + l_points() + l_fitLine() + l_ciLine()   # First
plot(getViz(b[[2]])) + l_points() + l_fitLine() + l_ciLine()   # Second
plot(getViz(b))   # Third
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, color = g)) + geom_point(pch = ".") + theme_bw() # Fourth
```

[image: First plot][image: Second plot]
[image: Third plot][image: Fourth plot]

I would like to combine the first two plots into one as is partially done in the third plot. Putting the third plot into the data shown in the fourth would do the trick. This also needs different intercept shifts in the third plot fits. Adding `l_points()` to the third plot renders it empty.

A hidden constraint is that the `gam` smooths are separate list components (as they are above) because they are actually coming from a custom clustering code for time series snippets of unequal length and spacing using mgcv's `bam` for very large data. So the plotting should preferably get all its information from `b`, a list `gam` results for each cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not **`mgcViz`**, but you can simply create the needed output yourself and use **`ggplot2`**:

```r
library(mgcv)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

n = 1e3
z = rnorm(n)
dat = data.frame(
  z = rep(z, times = 2),
  y = rep(c(1,2), each = n) + c(sin(z), 0.5*z^2) + rnorm(2*n)/4,
  g = factor(rep(1:2, each = n)))

b <- gam(y ~ g + s(z, by = g), data = dat)

ndf <- expand.grid(z = seq(min(dat$z), max(dat$z), length.out=100), g = unique(dat$g))
ndf$pred <- predict(b, newdata = ndf, type = "response")

ggplot(ndf, aes(x = z, y = pred, col = g)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(y = y))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

### Edit

If you want to fit separate models per group, could do something like this:

```r
library(purrr)
ndf <- map_dfr(
  .x = unique(dat$g),
  .f = ~{
    mod_i <- gam(y ~ s(x), data = dat[dat$g == .x, ])
    ndf_i <- expand.grid(x = seq(min(dat$x), max(dat$x), length.out = 100))
    ndf_i$g <- .x
    ndf_i$pred <- predict(mod_i, newdata = ndf_i, type = "response")
    ndf_i
  })

ggplot(ndf, aes(x = x, y = pred, col = g)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(y = y))
```

Comment: My `b` is a list of separate `gam` results for each cluster (I updated the question), so I don't have a single model with `g`. I could refit the model with the `g` intercepts but I wonder if this is avoidable as the data involved is large.

Comment: It works, with a little more data wrangling if one needs to start with `b` as a list of `gam` results in my question. Specifically, your `predict` is replaced with `do.call(c, lapply(b, predict, newdata = list(x = z), type = "response"))`.  Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeOstrouchov I've made an edit to the post per request. Note that in the one model version, you could also use function `mgcv::bam` instead of `gam`, with `method = "fREML"` and `discrete = TRUE`, to reduce computation time and memory requirements.